# Linq OrderBy alphabetically

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column with string content.

I want order the query results alphabetically by this column:

```
var query = db.Table.Where(q=>.....).OrderBy(q=>q.ColumnName);

foreach(var result in query){
    //do something
}
```

I think it's so easy but I obtain a System.NotSupportedException exception:
"An expression order by can contain non-constant scalar values that are comparable in terms of sorting from the server. The expression with type 'Text' is not comparable in terms of sorting."

Any idea?

Comment: `ORDER BY` cannot be used with text field. [This](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-420.aspx) should help.

Comment: Is your column a ntext field ? this field can't be used in an order by clause .